# Inline & not-inline

Tags: c++

Suppose I have:

```
struct Vec3 {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
} ;

inline double dot(const Vec3& lhs, const Vec3& rhs) {
  return lhs.x * rhs.x + lhs.y * rhs.y + lhs.z * rhs.z ;
}
```

Is it possible to have "dot" also exist in a non-inlined version, so that it can be in the *.so , so that when I dl open it I can call it?

I.e. I want files that include the above header to use the inlined version, but I also want the function to exist in a *.so, so I can dl open it and call it dynamically.

Comment: Don't mark it inline. Then it will appear in the shared library. And the compiler will still be able to inline it any normal code. (Note: They keyword inline has very little to do with the processes of actually in-lining code).

Comment: @Martin: Wouldn't that cause "multiple definitions" link errors?

Comment: @aschepler: depends: if its in a cpp, no inlining will occur (generally) but it will compile just fine, if its in a .hpp there might be inlining but you almost certainly will have multiple definitions(the inline keyword is to get those defs merged into one, not to make the compiler inline every use)

Comment: @flownt: If the compiler decides inlining is appropriate. It will happen if it is in the header or the source. Code **DOES not need to be visable** at the inline site for it to be inlined. Compilers are very smart nowadays.

Comment: @aschepler: Only if you put the code in the header file. You can put the code in the source file. Modern compilers are just as capable (or will be soon) to inline code across different translation units.

Comment: @Martin: In MSVC, that is called "whole-program optimization".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
inline double dot(const Vec3& lhs, const Vec3& rhs) {
    return lhs.x * rhs.x + lhs.y * rhs.y + lhs.z * rhs.z;
}

double dot(const Vec3* lhs, const Vec3* rhs) {
    return dot(*lhs, *rhs);
}
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that, if you then declare the "pointer" version as `extern "C"`, then C programs can use it too. (C does not support references, but does support pointers---so you cannot `extern "C"` the "reference" version.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the function via `dlopen`, it must be `extern "C"`.  Fun fact: you can put an `extern "C"` declaration inside a namespace, and the namespace is ignored for name mangling, but still makes a declaration there different from the global namespace declaration.

```
// something.h (C++)
inline double dot(const Vec3& lhs, const Vec3& rhs) { /*...*/ }

// something.cpp
namespace for_dlopen {
  extern "C" double dot(const Vec3& lhs, const Vec3& rhs)
  {
      return ::dot(lhs, rhs);
  }
}
```

Edit: Chris makes a good point - it's definitely not portable to `extern "C"` a function with reference parameters, but I believe it should work with g++ if you intend to only get it with `dlsym` and cast it to the original C++ type.

Comment: You didn't hear this from me, but I've (in a previous job) actually done stuff like `GetProcAddress` the mangled names of `extern "C++"` functions. :-) (And if it's good enough for `GetProcAddress`, I'm almost certain it's good enough for `dlsym`. :-P)